# scala: easier way to wrap an object inside another object

Tags: scala, inheritance, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

In a play 2.1 application I have the following code (it's just a request wrapper that gets rid of any trailing slash):

```
class NormalizedRequest(request: RequestHeader) extends RequestHeader {

  val headers = request.headers
  val id = request.id
  val method = request.method
  val queryString = request.queryString
  val remoteAddress = request.remoteAddress
  val tags = request.tags
  val version = request.version

  // strip first part of path and uri if it matches http.path config
  val path = if (request.path == "/") "/" else request.path.stripSuffix("/")
  val uri = path + {
    if(request.rawQueryString == "") ""
    else "?" + request.rawQueryString
  }
}

object NormalizedRequest {
  def apply(request: RequestHeader) = new NormalizedRequest(request)
}
```

This kind of code is pretty common, you just wrap an object inside another

I was wondering if there's an easier way to acomplish it, ideally it would be something like (pseudo code inspired on case classes):

```
object NormalizedRequest {
  def apply(request: RequestHeader) = {
    val path = if (request.path == "/") "/" else request.path.stripSuffix("/")
    val uri = path + {
      if(request.rawQueryString == "") ""
      else "?" + request.rawQueryString
    }
    request.copy(path = path, uri = uri)
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case I would use an implicit conversion to a structural type instead of actual wrapper type.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you're asking for a more concise version of the Decorator pattern in scala. You still need your "wrapper" to be the same type as you inner class (by extending it or a common base/trait) in order to be able to pass it over to some function that expects to receive an instance of the inner class (or of the common base/trait).

What you wrote in your pseudo code is actually almost legal scala, you just have to change the definition of `apply` in `NormalizedRequest` to return an anonymous class that extends RequestHeader.

I.e. instead of

```
class NormalizedRequest(request: RequestHeader) extends RequestHeader {
    //.... "decorated" logic here
}
object NormalizedRequest {
  def apply(request: RequestHeader) = new NormalizedRequest(request)
}
```

you would have

```
object NormalizedRequest {
  def apply(request: RequestHeader) = new RequestHeader {
    // ...
    // instead of having a separate NormalizedRequest class
    // define its behaviour here in anonymous form    
    }
}
```

A simplified example:

```
// our inner class and companion object 
// (a simplified version of your RequestHeader)
class Inner() {def test="hello"}; object Inner {
    def apply() = new Inner()
} 

// our wrapper
object Outer {
    def apply(inner: Inner) = new Inner {
        override def test=inner.test + "!"
    }   
}
```

however, although it saves you a few keystrokes, I really think you would lose in readability.